# Read google sheet by chunk

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, chunks

I have a large size google sheet. I read it from Python API. When load all data into memory, it run out of usage.

```
spreadsheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, includeGridData=True).execute()
```

It there any way that I can get this sheet by a given chunk size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [***ranges***](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.ranges) request parameter allows you to retrieve the specific info you want from your sheet. See this code as an example:

```py
ss_id = 'your-sheet-id'
# The range must be in A1 notation
ranges = "A1:B5"   
grid_data = True

sheet_range = service.spreadsheets()\
        .get(spreadsheetId=ss_id, ranges=ranges, includeGridData=grid_data).execute()
    
print(sheet_range)
```

### Docs

You can see more about the Sheets API in these links and you can even test it using the ***Try this API***:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).
- [REST Resource: spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets).
- [Google Sheets API](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/sheets_v4.html).